# The 404 not found image is not unique

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This site's `404 not found` image is not unique. It's shared with TeX SE.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/404
https://stats.stackexchange.com/404

It's entirely possible that this is intentional, but since most sites don't have the same image, I thought it was reasonable to suspect that it was a bug.

Sister bug report:
[on Meta TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/745/the-404-not-found-image-is-not-unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional. There are no special 404 and CAPTCHA images for tex.stackexchange.org yet and apparently Jin (the designer of these sites) decided that the CrossValidated images make good placeholders for the TeX site.